# TargetApi not taken into account

Tags: android, annotations, emulation

In one of our methods, we use smoothScrolling in a list view. As this method is not available before API Level 8 (FROYO), we used the TargetApi annotation to prevent the method from being called in previous SDK versions.

As you can see, we *do* use TargetApi annotation both in class definition and in statements that use the objects of the class. This is more than needed.

Our problem is that the TargetApi annotation is not taken into account and make our emulator crash in version ECLAIR (SDK 7). By tracing, we just realize that the code that should only be executed in versions 8+ is also executed in version 7.

Are we missing something?

This code is in a listener :

```
@TargetApi(8)
private final class MyOnMenuExpandListener implements OnMenuExpandListener {
    @Override
    public void onMenuExpanded( int position ) {
        doScrollIfNeeded( position );
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuCollapsed( int position ) {
        doScrollIfNeeded( position );
    }

    protected void doScrollIfNeeded( int position ) {
        if ( mListViewDocuments.getLastVisiblePosition() - 2 < position ) {
            mListViewDocuments.smoothScrollToPosition( position + 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

And the listener is registered this way :

```
@TargetApi(8)
private void allowSmothScrollIfSupported() {
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO ) {
        //This if should not be necessary with annotation but it is not taken into account by emulator
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Smooth scroll support installed." );
        folderContentAdapter.setOnMenuExpandListener( new MyOnMenuExpandListener() );
    }
}
```

BTW, we run the code in debug mode, so the issue is not related to obfuscation removing annotations.

Comment: BTW, you can write `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)` instead of `@TargetApi(8)`.

Comment: You are right. And for that your targetSDK must be as high as possible.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`@TargetApi` does not prevent any code from being run, it is merely for annotating code and preventing compiler errors for new APIs once you know you are only conditionally calling them.

You still need to add something along the lines of

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
    //...
}
```

Comment: all it does is remove lint errors. check [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheckhttp://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck)

Comment: really ?! It seems so. But it seems really strange to have a different system rather than @SuppressWarnings as we usually do to circumvent lint errors.

Comment: Indeed, it's just another form of annotation and the programatic method allows fine control of what is run.

Comment: Not only is @TargetApi redundent, but there is still no way to properly annotate the example you gave: neither annotation can be attached to the offending line, so they must be attached to the whole function (or the code in the if statement must be turned into a fn).  Why did Google add @TargetApi?

Answer (score 5):

With almost one year of more thinking about this, I would like to add a tiny complement to @Guykun 's answer :

The @TargetApi will be only be used by tools to say developers "Hey, don't use this method below XXX android SDK". Typically lint.

So, if you design a method like :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
    //...
}
```

then you should add @TargetApi( 7 ) to your method's signature.

*BUT*, if you add an else statement, and provide an alternative that makes it work for all versions of Android like :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

then you should ***not*** add @TargetApi( 7 ) to your method's signature. Otherwise, other developers will think they can't use your method belw api level 7, but indeed, it would work for them as well.

So this annotation has to be used, for static analysis, to indicate the minimum api level supported by the method. As in :

```
@TargetApi( 7 )
public void foo() {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
       //...
   else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10){
       //...
   } 
}
```

and even better, use constants defined in `android.Build.VERSION_CODES.*`.

BTW, you would have noticed that this is useless for private methods indeed, except to get a cleaner code and help to promote the method public in the future.

Comment: That's an answer to @Tom 's question.

Comment: I would think like you, but here's an excerpt from the code generated from Android Studio's LoginActivity wizard :

`@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
// ...
        } else {
// ...
        }
    }
`

Answer (score 1):

To enforce lint error when using a method targeted towards higher Api Level, you can use [`RequiresApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html) instead of [`TargetApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html) and whenever you'll try to use the method without checking the version code, you'll get compilation error.

This is what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html) says about [RequiresApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html)

> This is similar in purpose to the older @TargetApi annotation, but
>   more clearly expresses that this is a requirement on the caller,
>   rather than being used to "suppress" warnings within the method that
>   exceed the minSdkVersion.