# Android Lint - NewApi check still fails despite suppression with @TargetApi

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-lint

Following an unsuccessful Lint run, I attempted to fix an error by adding the `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)` attribute, but the next time Lint is run, the following error still shows for the [`getScaleX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScaleX()) function:

[image: Lint NewApi error message]

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211061/targetapi-not-taken-into-account  &   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341042/what-is-better-suppresslint-or-targetapi?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The call to [`getScaleX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScaleX()) requires API level 11 (Honeycomb), as mentioned in the message window. The message also indicates that the minimum API level is 9 (as per the [`minSdkVersion`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) setting).

The Lint tool is warning you that you are using a method supported only in newer SDK versions (11+), but have set to allow the application to run on devices that don't support this method (SDK versions 9 and 10).

See a more detailed description of what the NewApi Lint check does here: (search for NewApi) http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Suppress such warnings with caution, I'd suggest protecting the code with something like this:

```
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        ...getScaleX()...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately,it does not answer my question. What you proposed is exactly what I have been using.  My question is about why Lint check still fails, not about failure of code.  The code works perfectly on all versions of Android.

Comment: Do you have a version check around the code in question? I.e. something like `if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)`? If not, then if you're running on an earlier SDK version (on the device), then I'd expect the code to fail.

Comment: Yes, as my first comment states, my code is exactly like your answer.  Again, the code works perfectly and the app works fine.  It is just that it cannot pass Lint.

Comment: Does it still happen if you tag the method with `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` (as opposed to `@TargetApi`? Or putting the `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)` at the top of the class definition? I have similar code (using Android Studio, not Eclipse), and when I change the @TargetApi to the version targeted , despite the `minSdkVersion` being lower, the Lint message no longer appears.

Comment: Thanks for trying to lend a hand.  I am sorry but I have to say that I have given up.  The behavior of Lint check on my dev machine is erratic.  At this moment, it complains about certain functions in  commented out code.

Comment: Might be time to check out Android Studio :-)

Comment: I have been thinking about Android Studio, but it is still in beta.